# Strongswan connection without PSK

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

Is it possible to set up strongswan without pre shared secret and without a certificate for iOS/macOS? Only login and password.
My current method for iOS/macOS:

```
leftauth=psk
```

Comment: ikev2 allows username/password authentication as long as the server has a certificate with the Server Authentication EKU. If iOS can't do it in the UI, it may allow you to configure it with an XML profile. Have you looked into that?